# Componentes Livewire no funcionan en mi servidor de producción

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

estoy realizando una pequeña capacitación en Laravel + Livewire y no me están funcionando los componentes cuando los subo a mi servidor de internet, mientras que en mi entorno de desarrollo, funcionan bien. A continuación, les comparto el código que estoy utilizando.

Esta es la página principal donde estoy renderizando mi componente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        @livewire('compo1')
    </body>
</html>
```

y acá les muestro el componente:

```
<div>
    <button wire:click="CrearNuevoCurso()">Presionar Aca</button>
</div>


<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Compo1 extends Component
{
    public function CrearNuevoCurso(){
        dd(('Estoy en el componente'));
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.compo1');
    }
}
```

Este es el composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

por último, estoy intentando publicar esta pequeña app en un servidor compartido cuya ruta es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias y saludos.

Modifico la pregunta para comentar que el comportamiento que esperaba es que al dar click en el botón, se dispare el evento CrearNuevoCurso() y no se dispara. Haciendo una revisión con Inspeccionar del Crome, veo que aparece el siguiente error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () - livewire.js:1

Comment: Que es lo que "no funciona" de los componentes? Podrías ser más específico?

Comment: Ok, perdón, no puse cual es el comportamiento que esperaba. Simplemente hay que dar click en el botón para que se dispare el evento click y sea atrapado por la función CrearNuevoCurso() y esto es lo que no funciona, no se dispara el evento.

Comment: Probaste sacando los parentesis? `wire:click="CrearNuevoCurso"`. Tambien te sugiero no usar `dd()` para debugar, ya que mata el proceso. Usa `Log::debug` o alguna herramienta más potente como xdebug

Comment: Y viendo ahora lo que agregaste a la pregunta: **the server responded with a status of 404 ()** ¿a que url se refiere ese mensaje?

Comment: Me da la sensación de que está buscando el archivo livewire.js y no lo encuentra. Por algún lado leí que hay problemas cuando querés instalar tu app en un server compartido, tal como lo estoy haciendo yo. Ya probé lo que dice la documentación de livewire y sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente tengas que ver el archivo de configuración de livewire.
Este archivo esta dentro de la carpeta config  y se llama livewire.php.
en este archivo hay una seccion que se llama

Livewire Assets URL

ahí livewire configura la url de acceso a las librerias.

lo normal es que este de la siguiente manera

```
   'asset_url' => 'http://localhost/NOMBRE DE TU PROYECTO/public',
```

deberías cambiar ese localhost por la ip o dominio de tu servidor.

Saludos